# Converting request form data ( images) to bytes

Tags: vue.js, flask

I'm getting formdata from my client side, this is a image data. On the backend I have a flask server running in which I have to convert this data to numpy array so that I can pass this value to my process function(basically a model that takes blur images and converts into better quality)

I have tried whole lot different options, such as tried to convert the data into bytes, cv2 file read etc. I have been stuck on this for a while. Any direction is appreciated

```
 const fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("project", this.imgUrl);

    const options = {
      method: "POST",      
      body: fd, 

    };
    // delete options.headers["Content-Type"];

    fetch("http://172.16.1.34:1234/api/test", options)
      .then(res => res)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
```

```py
def test():
    # if request.method == 'POST':
        # print('Here')
        # print(request.files)
        # something = request.form['project']
        # print(something)
        #
        # print(type(something))
        # print(len(something))
        # img = cv2.imread(something)
        # image = process_image(img)
        # print("im here")

     if request.method == 'POST':
        print("inside")
        photo = request.form['project']
        print(photo)
        # try:
        #     delete_files("./temp_results")
        # except:
        #     pass
        # filename = secure_filename(image.filename)
        # image.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        #
        # img_name = os.listdir("./temp_results")[0]
        #
        # image = cv2.imread('./temp_results/' + img_name)
        # print(image.shape)
        # # processed_image = process_image(image)
        # scipy.misc.imsave("./temp_results/temp.png", processed_image)
     return jsonify({'Hello': True})


#     scipy.misc.imsave(image,'./temp_results/temp.png')

#     return send_file("./temp_results/temp.png", attachment_filename='temp.png')
```

I want to convert this form data into numpy array

Comment: try to add headers with headers: {
  "Content-type":
    "multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8; boundary=" +
    Math.random()
      .toString()
      .substr(2)
}

Comment: Nope, didn't work